# React/Html: Changing the color of what has been selected.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm working on a class project, and I'm a bit stuck.  In my app, I'd like to be able to change the color of text that has been selected.  So, in this case, I'd like the 'h2' tag that is clicked, to turn red if it's selected by the user.

I'm still new to react, so figuring how to bind stuff has been a bit difficult. 
 I don't want to set a new state either, because there are multiple 'h2' tags, so if one is changed, my concern is that all the others will change too.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UpdateReasons from '../../actions/updateReasons.js';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
// import ReasonStyle from './reasons.css'; note: imported via index.html // style folder
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';

class ReasonsHappy extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      reasons: []
    }
  }

  reply_click(clicked_value) {
    const reasons = [];
    reasons.push(clicked_value)
    this.setState({
      reasons: this.state.reasons.concat(reasons)
    })

  }

  render() {


    return (

      <div className='buttonDiv {ReasonStyle}'>

        <h2 id = 'reasonsId' active = 'false' onClick={() => {this.reply_click("Great Culture")}} type="button" className="btn btn-lg reason" value={"Great Culture"}> <b> Great Culture </b> </h2>
        <h2 id = 'reasonsId' active = 'false' onClick={() => {this.reply_click("Flexible Managers")}} type="button" className="btn btn-lg reason" value={"Flexible Managers"}> <b> Flexible Managers </b> </h2>
        <h2 id = 'reasonsId' active = 'false' onClick={() => {this.reply_click("Friendly Co-workers")}} type="button" className="btn btn-lg reason" value={"Friendly Co-workers"}> <b> Friendly Co-workers </b> </h2>
        <h2 id = 'reasonsId' active = 'false' onClick={() => {this.reply_click("Upbeat Work Environment")}} type="button" className="btn btn-lg reason" value={"Upbeat Work Environment"}> <b> Upbeat Work Environment </b> </h2>
        <h2 id = 'reasonsId' active = 'false' onClick={() => {this.reply_click("Work is Appreciated")}} type="button" className="btn btn-lg reason" value={"Work is Appreciated"}> <b> Work is Appreciated </b> </h2>
        <h2 id = 'reasonsId' active = 'false' onClick={() => {this.reply_click("Flexible Work Hours")}} type="button" className="btn btn-lg reason" value={"Flexible Work Hours"}> <b> Flexible Work Hours </b> </h2>
        <h2 id = 'reasonsId' active = 'false' onClick={() => {this.reply_click("New Opportunities")}} type="button" className="btn btn-lg reason" value={"New Opportunities"}> <b> New Opportunities </b> </h2>

        <br></br>

        <p id='submitP'>
          <Link to="/stats">
            <FontAwesome name="arrow-circle-right" id="arrow" onClick={() => {UpdateReasons(this.state.reasons)}}/>
          </Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
};


export default ReasonsHappy;
```

Any direction on this would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: First one, you are putting the same id='reasonsId' to all div, don't do that. Second, if its a list of H2, put on List with key: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should realy read and learn about [react components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) and how to pass `props` and `handlers`.  You can't pass `props` or none native attributes to real `DOM` elements.  and also read how to [thinking in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

You can create  component that can accept and `id`, `active` and an `onClick` handler that will pass back to the parent the current item `id` that was clicked. The parent will set this `id` in its state and will conditionally pass the `active` props respectively.

Here is a small running example to get you started:

```js
class Item extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const { itemId, onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(itemId);
  }
  render() {
    const { text, active } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={`header ${active && 'active'}`} onClick={this.handleClick}>{text}</div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeItem: 0,
      items: [
        {
          text: 'item 1',
          id: 1
        },
        {
          text: 'item 2',
          id: 2
        },
        {
          text: 'item 3',
          id: 3
        },
        {
          text: 'item 4',
          id: 4
        },
      ]
    }
  }

  onItemClick = (id) => {
    this.setState({ activeItem: id });
  }

  render() {
    const { items, activeItem } = this.state;
    return (
      <div >
        {
          items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <Item
                key={item.id}
                text={item.text}
                itemId={item.id}
                onClick={this.onItemClick}
                active={item.id === activeItem}
              />
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.header{
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This answered my question! I modified it so that [activeItem] is an array and updated the rest of what you wrote so that it shows multiple 'active' buttons at once. Thanks!